# Gradients not populating as expected

Tags: pytorch

Sorry, I know questions of this sort have been asked a lot, but I still don't understand the behavior of autograd.

A simple example is below:

```
ce_loss=torch.nn.BCELoss()
par=torch.randn((1,n),requires_grad=True)
act=torch.nn.Sigmoid()

y_hat=[]
for obs in data:
    y_hat.append(act(par@obs))

loss=ce_loss(torch.tensor(y_hat,requires_grad=True),y)
loss.backward()
```

After applying backward, the grad of par remains None (although it is a leaf node with requires_grad=True).

Any tips?

Comment: I run your code and it works I can see grads from `loss` and from `par` (I had to create `y` vector and `data`). Gradients are stored in `par.grad`. When you do the backward you compute the gradients and for perfoming the gradient descent you only have to init an optimizer and then run `optim.step()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply because `torch.tensor(...)` create a **new leaf** of the computational graph. It means by definition that the operation inside `torch.tensor` are blocked, in particular the computation using elements of `par` (and so, the grads are never computed). Note that adding `requires_grad=True` doesn't change anything because it always creates a leaf (with grads) that forgot the previous operations by definition of a leaf.

I suggest you an other way to make your computation without iterate on `data` and using native parallelization:

```py
batch_size, n = 8, 10  # or something else

# Random data and labels to reproduce the code
data = torch.randn((batch_size, n))
y = torch.randn((batch_size, ))

y = y.unsqueeze(1)  # size (batch_size, 1)
ce_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss()
par = torch.randn((1, n), requires_grad=True)
act = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

y_hat = act(data @ par.T)  # compute all predictions in parallel

loss = ce_loss(y_hat, y)  # automatically reduced to scalar (mean)
loss.backward()

print(par.grad)  # no longer None!
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did notice that feeding in a matrix to the above doesn't have the same issue. Unfortunately my real use case is not neatly treated in parallel